# Sencha Ext JS hot reload / live update

Tags: extjs, browser-sync, sencha-cmd, hot-reload, live-update

I'm running **Ext JS 6.2** and one feature I miss compared to new frameworks is hot reload / live reload during development (both for js files and css files). Press F5 every **X** second to refresh the page is time-wasting

I tried to configure `browsersync` with `vagrant` but the watcher doesn't watch the right files maybe. Since sencha has `sencha app watch` and from Sencha 6.2 there's also a new feature called "**Fashion**" I thought there was also some option/workaround to enable "page refresh"

How I can configure hot reload in Sencha?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, hot reload is [not supported](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?332537-Hot-Reloading). For `browsersync` to work, you must specify the build folder if it is used with `sencha cmd`, or the `app` folder if you do not build the application. For example, I use browsersync in spring java and I have to specify the folder of the folder in which the maven collects all the files. If you use Sencha CMD, it should auto-update itself, but slowly.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! What I don't figure out is that they already have implemented ```sencha app watch``` what does it cost to add an option into the ```cmd``` to open a browser tab or refresh the current one?